# Using a promoted data constructor as a phantom parameter

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

In Maguire's *Thinking with Types*, p. 29, there's an example of how to use a promoted data constructor as a phantom parameter. Here's a module that I wrote based on the example in the book.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Main where

import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Proxy

-- | The only purpose of this constructor is to give us access to its
--   promoted data constructors.
data UserType = DummyUser | Admin

-- | Give some users an administration token.
data User = User
  { userAdminToken :: Maybe (Proxy 'Admin),
    name           :: String
  }

doSensitiveThings :: Proxy 'Admin -> IO ()
doSensitiveThings _ = putStrLn "you did something sensitive"

trustedUser :: User
trustedUser = User (Just (Proxy :: Proxy Admin)) "Trust me"

main = do
    doSensitiveThings (fromJust . userAdminToken $ trustedUser)
```

I understand that this makes it impossible to call `doSensitiveThings` without an administration token. **But I feel I'm missing something important.
How is the code above better than the code below?**

```
module Main where

import           Data.Maybe

data Admin = Admin

data User a = User String

doSensitiveThings :: User Admin -> IO ()
doSensitiveThings _ = putStrLn "you did something sensitive"

trustedUser :: User Admin
trustedUser = User "Trust me"

untrustedUser :: User ()
untrustedUser = User "Don't trust me"

main = do
    doSensitiveThings trustedUser
    -- doSensitiveThings untrustedUser -- won't compile
```

Comment: I don't like the original code. If we used `trustedUser = User Nothing "Do not trust me"` it would still make the code compile and even run the "sensible" part! Your code is better, IMO. I'd still write `data User (a :: UserType) = User String` so to completely prevent `User ()`, which now becomes a kind error.

Comment: The big thing about a phantom type is that it should be visible but not affect runt time representation. Your `User` example kind of does neither of those.

Comment: In your second version, you should use a *role annotation* to protect the phantom from safe corrections. Enable `{-# RoleAnnotations #-}` and then add `type role User nominal` where you define your type. Now `Data.Coerce.coerce :: User a -> User Admin` won't type-check.

Comment: s/corrections/coercions in my last comment.

Comment: What is `DummyUser` doing in the first example? It isn't mentioned anywhere else; is that on purpose?

Comment: This toy example is so trivial that its difficult to argue based on the pragmaticism of either one. Purely from this standpoint, both are useless in terms of preventing unauthorized access to `doSensitiveThings`. Furthermore, neither method is strictly more general than the other, and they are not equivalent, so it isn't "better" or "worse", rather just "different".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, now there's no such thing as "a `User`". A `User Admin` and a `User ()` now have different types, so you cannot treat them the same as e.g. elements of a list:

```
users :: [User] -- ill-kinded!
users = [User "untrusted" :: User (), User "trusted" :: User Admin] -- ill-typed!
```

You also can no longer branch based on whether a user is an admin or not (remember that Haskell *is* type-erased!):

```
displayActions :: User a -> [String]
displayActions (User name) =
    ["Delete My Account (" ++ name ++ ")"] ++ (if isAdmin u then ["Delete Someone Else's Account"] else [])
isAdmin :: User a -> Bool -- this function can take either User Admin or User ()...
isAdmin = ??? -- ...but how's it supposed to branch on that?
```

So maybe try

```
data SomeUser = SomeAdmin (User Admin) | SomeNormalUser (User ())
```

But now we're basically doing the same thing in your first example (where `User Admin` becomes the token type instead of `Proxy Admin`) except it's just worse. There's just a lot code noise.

```
name :: SomeUser -> String -- having to write your own accessor functions over pattern matching/record fields; ew
name (SomeAdmin (User x)) = x
name (SomeNormalUser (User x)) = x -- ugly pattern matching and same code twice; ew
isAdmin :: SomeUser -> Bool
isAdmin (SomeAdmin _) = True
isAdmin _ = False

displayActions :: SomeUser -> [String] -- having both SomeUser and User instead of just one type and having to know which one to use in any given situation; ew
displayActions u =
    ["Delete My Account (" ++ name u ++ ")"] ++ (if isAdmin u then ["Delete Someone Else's Account"] else [])
```

I do see something wrong with the original, and I believe it's what confused you. The "only" "good thing" in the original code is the existence of the token type. Using `Proxy` with a type parameter to construct the token type instead of doing

```
data AdminToken = AdminToken
```

is (IMO) pointless and confusing (both for understanding the technique and also in the resulting code). The type parameter is *irrelevant* to what makes the idea good, and you gain nothing by keeping the type parameter and not the token. I consider the following to be an *actual* improvement to the original while keeping its good idea.

```
data User = { userAdminToken :: Maybe AdminToken; userName :: String }
isAdmin :: User -> Bool
isAdmin = isJust . userAdminToken

displayActions :: User -> [String]
displayActions u
    ["Delete My Account (" ++ userName u ++ ")"] ++ (if isAdmin u then ["Delete Someone Else's Account"] else [])
```

Answer (score 2):

With the original code, you can write:

```
trustedUser = User (Just Proxy) "trusted"
untrustedUser = User Nothing "untrusted"

twoUsers :: [User] -- or Map Username User or whatever
twoUsers = [trustedUser, untrustedUser]
```

You can't make a similar `twoUsers` list with the second code snippet, because your trusted and untrusted users have different types.